# Set id of the generated element

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I am using angular-kendo. Is there any option to set the `id` of the generated element.

```
<div  ng-controller="HomeCtrl" kendo-tree-view k-options="subjects"></div>
```

Becomes an `ul` but I would like to set the `id` of this `ul` in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the "id" of the generated `ul` element. However you can set the `id` of the `div` itself:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl" id="treeview" kendo-tree-view k-options="subjects"></div>
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ezOPUta/2/edit

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. And I realize it cant be to better I will accept this.